# Watir Scroll For All Comments

Tags: watir

I'm trying to scroll until there are no more contents on a `Youtube` video.  I'm testing a counter versus the current number of comments displayed.

```
mycount = 0
1.upto(20) do
  thiscount = browser.div(id: "contents").divs(id: "comment-content").size
  puts "#{ mycount } : #{ thiscount }"
  break if mycount == thiscount
  mycount = thiscount
  browser.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")
  sleep 10
end
```

After the first `pagedown`, the count of comments should increase.  It isn't.  I've entered a `sleep 10` for the comments to load and the count of those comments to also update.  It doesn't update.  I keep getting **20 : 20** so it breaks and leaves this iteration after a single iteration.

I'm not sure why that valuation isn't updating.  How can I fix this so that it can get to the end of the comments?

Comment: hard to know exactly what you are trying to do here. Watir has a much more powerful scrolling API than execute script. You can see details here - http://watir.com/watir-7-2/#advanced-scrolling

Comment: ` undefined method `from' for #<Watir::Browser::Scroll:0x000000010bde5a88 @browser=#<Watir::Browser:0x2f43ead253883880 closed=true>> (NoMethodError)`. That isn't the issue.  Scrolling isn't the problem.  It's assessing the updated count of `elements` and comparing it to my last count.  I'm not clear why after the scroll, Watir doesn't see the new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into 2 problems when running your script:

1. `browser.div(id: "contents").divs(id: "comment-content")` returned nothing. There were many "contents" divs, with the first one not including any comments. I removed this locator.
2. Scrolling by 1000 is not enough to get to the bottom of the page. Therefore the loading of additional comments does not get triggered.

From the following script:

```
scroll_by = 1000000000000

browser.goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9DPBxiZZfo&ab_channel=America%27sTestKitchen')
browser.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,#{scroll_by})")
sleep 15
mycount = 0
1.upto(20) do
  thiscount = browser.divs(id: "comment-content").size
  puts "#{ mycount } : #{ thiscount }"
  break if mycount == thiscount
  mycount = thiscount
  browser.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,#{scroll_by})")
  sleep 10
end
```

You can see that having a larger scroll gives the expected results:

```
0 : 20
20 : 40
40 : 60
60 : 80
80 : 100
100 : 120
120 : 140
140 : 160
160 : 180
180 : 185
185 : 185
```

In contrast, setting the `scroll_by` to just "1000" did not trigger the comments. The output was just:

```
0 : 0
```

Comment: That's not the goal of that scroll.  That goal is to just scroll down.  Scrolling down by 10,000 or 100,000, might not hit the end of the page.  You don't know how many `elements` there are.  You test it by scrolling down until there are no more.  Your value might not work.  There's a problem with your code.  There's a problem with `Watir` that it doesn't update the `element` count.  It's a very poor way of approaching this.  Scrolling by 20 introduces new `elements` and `Watir` doesn't see this.

Comment: I updated the answer with the script I used and the output it gave. From the output, Watir is getting the updated element count. Do you get a different result when you run the script?

Comment: The script works.  The issue here is that `Watir` doesn't recognize the new introductions of any elements.  The expectation is that `Watir` should see this, not that this instance works.  Reduce `scroll_by` to 50 and that would demonstrate where the problem is.

Comment: As well, the script works here with those `locators`.

Comment: With a `scroll_by=50`, Watir doesn't find any comments. However, if I do it manually (ie by hand not using Watir), I get the same behaviour (no comments are triggered). So I don't understand what elements Watir is failing to recognize.

Comment: In your browser, open the page.  Select Page Down on your keyboard.  New comments arrive, which are new elements.  They should be recognized by `Watir`.  They aren't.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```rb
total = 0
while true
   before = browser.divs(id: "comment-content").count
   browser.div(id: "columns").scroll.to :bottom
   sleep 10 # or sleep 5
   total = browser.divs(id: "comment-content").count
   puts "There are #{total} comments for now" 
   break if before == total 
end
puts "There are #{total} comments in total"
```

instead `while true` you can use `20.times do` but that would only count up to ~400 comments.